# Получить идентификатор окна из CreateProcess.

Tags: winapi, c++

Как можно получить хэндл приложения, открытого функцией CreateProcess? Допустим, так открываю:

```
CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Функция возвращает BOOL. А как же тогда можно получить хэндл окна созданного процесса?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

Comment: Будьте внимательнее! Мне нужен не идентификатор созданного процесса, а идентификатор окна, созданного процесса CreateProcess!

Comment: Вы сами попросили хендл процесса: "А как же тогда можно получить хэндл созданного процесса?"
Заодно ответьте мне на вопрос, а всегда ли при создании процесса будет окно, хендл которого можно получить!?!?

Comment: Ээ, ну так а при запуске окна Блокнота, что же, процесс не создается? :) `notepad.exe` - вот он.

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то!

Comment: Да и тем более, хэндл процесса уже хранится в структуре &pi, так что это полная чушь...

Comment: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=360427

Answer (score 4):

Получить хэндл нужного окна можно следующим путем:

1. Запустить процесс - `CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`
2. Дождаться запуска и завершения инициализации процесса - `WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 10000);`
3. Проверить все созданные процессом окна - `EnumThreadWindows(pi.dwThreadId, (WNDENUMPROC)myEnumProc, (LPARAM)myParam);`. В callback функции `myEnumProc` по известным Вам критериям выбрать нужное окно (его хэндл).